# how to filter an input so that it will only output alphabet

Tags: python, filter

I am a beginner python user and I am working on a school project. Is there a way to get a user input but filter it so that it will only output a lowercase alphabet letter? Also, ask the user again until the user gives an acceptable answer.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and [mcve]